# Insert statement usage in SQL injection

Tags: mysql, select, sql-injection

I'm working through an SQL injection tutorial. I don't understand one aspect of an SQL statement which is used determine where the different columns in the table will be displayed on the web page and then used to execute statements. A previous SQL injection statement has been used to determine the number of columns in the table, which is 6. The SQL statement is

```
SELECT * FROM TableName Where id=12 union all select 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I've researched the SELECT and UNION ALL statements and haven't been able to work out what is actually going on. My thinking is that the numbers in the 2nd select statement respresent the column numbers.

The second statement used to get the values from the table is:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName Where id=12 union all select 1,2,3,4,user(),6
```

What does the select 1,2,3,4,5,6 and select 1,2,3,4, user(),6 component of the SQL injection query actually do?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik Good point there isn't actually a direct question in there will update to reflect what the question actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not column numbers but values.  Assuming you can somehow inject the statement you now need something to do with it.  The first example counts the columns.  the`UNION` will fail when there are not enough columns.  By adding more columns to the `UNION` eventually the statement will execute.  Now you know how many columns there are.

The second one is injecting the user into the return result set.  Assuming the result set gets displayed on the screen for some reason, you now have a user name (or service account name) with which to execute more statements on your database, escalate privileges or make service calls.

It's doing something like that.  Without knowing more it's hard to know what exactly.

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for. I'd overlooked the fact that the second select statement doesn't have either a from or where statement. Thank you.